# Manipulação de Scripts e propriedades Unity3D?

Tags: unity3d

Boa tarde pessoal!

Seguinte, estou enfrentando um problema. Estou desenvolvendo um jogo, onde há um script chamado de PlayerModel, que ao iniciar a Batalha, ele vem com dados que foram pre-definidos no script da Model, no entanto, ao terminar a batalha e tentar acessar um menu onde tem um HUD, não estou conseguindo trazer os dados (nome, level, exp, etc). Se eu utilizo um GameObject e dou um "**gameObject.GetComponent<>()**", considerando que tem um objeto player na Hierarchy, ele funciona. No entanto, se eu tento fazer o mesmo sem ter o GameObject, seja tentando utilizar o **AddComponent()** ou o **GetComponent()**, ele vem com os valores vazios! Alguém saberia me dizer como passar parâmetros, ou utilizar parâmetros estáticos/globais efetivamente?

Edit: outra coisa é que quando entro na batalha, saio e entro novamente, ele volta como se fosse a primeira vez, ele está "resetando" os status.

Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma para manter esses dados globais é a com a utilização do PlayerPrefs
com ele você seta valores e pega valores de qualquer lugar em seu jogo.

Segue o link da documentação:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html